# Missing parameter type in applyOrElse Scala

Tags: scala, partialfunction

I have this code where I'm trying to call a partial function. When I build my project I get an error stating `missing parameter type ++ headerExtractor.applyOrElse(event, _ => Map.empty)`.

I've looked at other posts, but I feel like this should be working. What am I doing wrong?

I'm calling headerExtractor here

```
private def publishToProfileExchange(customer: Schema.Customer, event: Schema.CustomerEvent): Future[Done] = {
  val messageType: String = "ProfileEvent"
  val headers: Map[String, AnyRef] = Map(
    "profileId" -> customer.id.toString,
    "eventType" -> event.eventType,
    "type" -> messageType
  ) ++ headerExtractor.applyOrElse(event, _ => Map.empty)

  ...
  //valid return values would be here
}

private val headerExtractor: PartialFunction[Schema.CustomerEvent, Map[String, AnyRef]] = {
    case x if x.eventType.equalsIgnoreCase("message") && (x.eventData \ "incoming").asOpt[Boolean].getOrElse(false) =>
       Map("incomingMessage" -> "true")
}
```

Comment: The result of `applyOrElse` is discarded as `Unit` (would raise compilation warning with appropriate options)

Comment: see my edit. I'm not just wanting to return right away.

Comment: Using `Any` or `AnyRef` lessen the type safety and prevent help from the compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to provide the **type of paramater** on your `.applyOrElse()`. See example below

```
case class CustomerEvent(eventType: String, eventData: String)

val headerExtractor = new PartialFunction[CustomerEvent, Map[String, AnyRef]] {
  def apply(x: CustomerEvent): Map[String, AnyRef] = Map("incomingMessage" -> "true")
  def isDefinedAt(x: CustomerEvent): Boolean = x.eventType.equalsIgnoreCase("message")
}

assert(headerExtractor.applyOrElse(CustomerEvent("message", "{}"), (customerEvent: CustomerEvent) => Map.empty)
  == Map("incomingMessage" -> "true"))

// or simply do (_: CustomerEvent)

assert(headerExtractor.applyOrElse(CustomerEvent("message", "{}"), (_: CustomerEvent) => Map.empty)
      == Map("incomingMessage" -> "true"))
```

negative case

```
assert(headerExtractor.applyOrElse(CustomerEvent("something-else", "{}"), (_: CustomerEvent) => Map.empty) 
== Map())
```

Comment: I've updated the line to `) ++ headerExtractor.applyOrElse(event, customer: CustomerEvent => Map.empty)` but it's not working

Comment: its not `_: CustomerEvent`, its `(_: CustomerEvent)` or `(customer: CustomerEvent)`